# Which account we should use to manage MS Flow connections

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, administration, ms-flow

I always uses our offcie 365 to create MS Flows which trigger when addiing/updating sharepoint list items, for example I have created an MS Flow which uses connection to :-

1. Send emails to users using exchange connector.
2. Send Approval emails
3. Connect to SharePoint list

as follow:-

[image]

now i created the MS flow using the office 365 admin user, but this user might face these issues in the future:-

1. Its password will get expired.
2. The username might be changed/removed

so what will happen to the connections inside the MS flow if any of the above 2 points happen to the user? will the connection stop working? and if the answer is Yes, then how i can overcome this problem that might occur by time?

For example, atleast for the password, we have the password expires each 3 months, and there might be a time where the password is expired without been directly renewed, so will the connection stop working from the time the password is expired till it is renewed?

Answer (score 1):

If you perform those one of two actions, yes the flows would stop working. You should consider creating an account dedicated to flow actions only granting the permission it requires to perform those actions. This account should have MFA enabled and based on your concerns, password expiry disabled.

Comment: ok noted thanks for the reply.. so currently if i create such an account can i transfer the connections' users to use this service account instead of the office 365 admin account? second point, what are the permissions i need to grant to the service account to be able to access the SharePoint list, send approvals emails + send emails using exchange/outlook connectors (as shown in the picture inside my question)? thanks

Comment: You should grant the permission required to perform the action where authentication is required on the trigger/action. Once you've validated permissions, then you can begin switching your triggers/actions over to the new account.

Comment: i will add the service account as site collection admin to be able to perform CRUD operations on the SharePoint list which is needed by the MS Flow.. but what permission the service account need to be able to send emails using Approvals + Exchange/outlook connectors?